# Pushing data to input() not getting detected: Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a parent component with an object called 'data', which contains some data that I want to display on the UI. The data is displayed in a table and I've created a child component that contains that table. So while calling the table component, I'm passing the data as @Input().

// parent componene template

```
<display-data [data]='data'></display-data>
```

On top of displaying, I have two methods in my parent component that modified this data property. One of that re-assigns the data array with something like this:

```
setNewData() {
  this.data = this.response.content;
}
```

and another method pushes the new data to already existing data:

```
addNewData(newData: Array) {
  this.data.push(...newData);
}
```

Because I'm using Angular Input(), I assume that whenever the I modify the data object in the parent component (re-assignment or adding more data), the data property in the child component will be updated instantly and I will see the new data on the UI. That works as expected.
BUT, when I tried looking at Angular's life cycle hook 'ngOnChanges', I noticed that it only gets called when the re-assignment happens, and not when I push some new data in the data object.

Is this how ngOnChanges works? Because I want to call a method whenever the data changes in the child component.

Comment: An alternative would be to pass each item in the source array to an individual component @Input() to track the changes of each item. Rather than the whole array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly how ngOnChanges work.

ngOnChanges gets called only when re-assignment happens.

If you want to have a method executed whenever this data changes, you can do the following.

1. Create a service with member variable data, and a function that returns this variable.
2. Parent Component can use this service's methods to fetch and update this variable.
3. The Service also contains an Event Emitter Object, which can be subscribed by the child component.
4. So, now whenever the parent component calls the service method to update the value of data, you can do that and also emit on the EventEmitter object.

Let me know if you want some kind of code for that. But you'll understand a lot if you code on your own.

Comment: thanks Aman. Even I had thought of doing the same for parent and child component communication, but just wanted some clarification on ngOnChanges(). I guess I will create a service instead of using Inputs for communication. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help :)